How to block request with specific header with Chrome's Network Panel in Developer Tools?
I'm trying to block any request that is a POST to some url and has a very specific header (to be precise, it has in the header Operation-Name: CLCSInterstitialLolomo).
With the chrome network pane, I can block all requests to the url (regardless of header). I'm referencing https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network-request-blocking
However, I want to only block those with that specific header – how would I achieve that?
